# How to reinforce forward propagation signal in deep learning network?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, backpropagation, forward, matconvnet

I've asked a question earlier at 
[Matconvnet output of deep network's marix is uniform valued instead of varying values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463853/matconvnet-output-of-deep-networks-marix-is-uniform-valued-instead-of-varying-v)
As I debugged the deep network for density estimation, I realized the signal towards the output dies out/fades. How can I reinforce the signal so that it doesn't become flat- and the peak and base values keep a high amplitude?[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming problem as the question stands now..

Answer (score 1):

Using lower alpha in LRN normalization can reinforce the output.